# Struggling to remove server from Rack

Tags: hp, rackmount

currently racking my brain at this one, i'm struggling to remove the below server out of the rack, I haven't come across this type of rail before, usually I can pull a server out and there will be clips which once pressed I can lift it up.

Can anyone spot the obvious thing i'm missing?

[image]

Comment: It looks like you push the spring clip on the inner rail and then pull the server out.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Push in the red circled area. This will move the tab in the blue circled area clear of the stop, and you can then pull the server out.
[image]

Comment: This is the right answer. And it's pretty common amongst server brands.

Comment: It's designed this way at least partly because your hands are then near the center of mass for the server as you unlock it, giving you a more stable grip and applying less torque to your hands and wrists.

Comment: Not to the OP, specifically: If not experienced with these kinds of rail systems, it is best not to work alone at first - dropping a 2U server on yourself, or losing your balance, or making a sparsely populated rack topple are all experiences best enjoyed in company.

Comment: @rackandboneman you're right - its a two person job.  Or ask your DC for their platform lift.  Most datacenters have something that looks like this : https://www.northerntool.com/images/product/2000x2000/445/44502_2000x2000.jpg  or the flash ones might have  http://alum-a-lift.com/sitefiles/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/21742-Side-to-Side-Roller-Deck-Lift-for-Servers.jpg   It only takes dropping one server to make these things worth the cost, plus avoiding the back strain.  Comment cos not an answer.

Comment: You might clarify that by "pulling the server out" you mean "keep pulling the server horizontally away from the rack until it completely slides out of the rails." The asker is expecting to lift the server up off the rails, as is common with Dell 2U Rapid Rails.

Comment: @ToddWilcox based on my experience with them I absolutely detest those "drop it on" rails.  Last thing I want to be doing when handling a big heavy server is trying to line up two flimsy pieces of metal with 4 mating pegs.

Comment: Hi all, apologies for the delay in responding to this - attempted the above with my manager and we couldn't get it to pull out even though the tabs were released on both sides, - we believe now something is causing it to Jam which is why i was so stumped, thanks for all the help!

Comment: also @rackandboneman i was close to kicking it out - it's a dead server which will be destroyed, it's a nice enclosure though so we plan on keeping it haha